# PHP, Zend Framework, Wordpress, need to find some clarity

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

First off, I'm new to web development. I am fairly comfortable with HTML/CSS, and I am building my first site for a friend's business. I want to include a contact form, so I downloaded one from CodeCanyon.  It is perfectly fine, but I'm in this to *learn* how to do this, so I scrapped the downloaded form and set out to learn some PHP.  (I realize that later on, from a profitability standpoint, it may be a wiser decision to use these types of plugins rather than doing it all myself; would love opinions on this as well).

I learnt how to write a simple e-mail contact form from some tutorials online, but quickly found there's much more to it when you get into address validation, and preventing spammers from hijacking your form, etc.  Should I continue to try to learn how to do the whole thing myself? If so, What is the best resource available?

I noticed people saying great things about Zend framework.  Can someone explain what it is in simple terms?

Also, I haven't used Wordpress yet, but it seems the best use of this (aside from using it to create quick websites on the cheap) is as a CMS so your clients can update their content later.  Does Zend framework also have some kind of CMS element to it?

I know this is kind of a complicated series of questions, but I'm trying to get some clarity.  To those of you who have been at this a while, all the different products, languages, acronyms, etc. may seem like a piece of cake, but to a newbie like me, its hard to figure it all out without some kind of sounding board.

Comment: This is off-topic, but FWIW: you are choosing between _frameworks_ (Zend, Symfony, Cake) and _CMS systems_ (Wordpress, Drupal, Typo3) - though there is some overlap between these terms! Frameworks are extremely well-structured and are general systems that contain a lot of commonly-used things in web development, like ORMs, validation, form components, email libraries, i18n etc. You need to have a reasonable level of programming skill for this approach. Conversely, a CMS is plug-and-play and at a basic level requires no coding skills.

Comment: Note that you could write a full web application using Wordpress (though the internals are arguably a good deal messier than a well-structured Zend or Symfony app) or you could write a CMS using Symfony (but you are competing with several years worth of expert development from Wordpress et al). So, what you need depends on your requirements. If you want to learn PHP, use a framework, but be prepared for a non-shallow learning curve.

Comment: ok, all of this is good advice; I appreciate it.  I think for now I will continue to focus on just learning PHP as best I can and leave the framework stuff for a later date.  As established as Wordpress is, I don't have a huge interest in getting involved with it...maybe that's a mistake..

Comment: Remember, it you are going to be learning PHP, as a general rule, *only use code from the PHP website (http://php.net)*. Other 'tutorials' tend be very outdated, especially with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of an open question but:

Zend Framework is a set of libraries that help you create php applications. They have a set of predefined classes that simplify tasks like Access Control List (User Login and such) or access Google APIs (like calendar and email). To take advantage of those libraries you need to interact with them in the programing level. (that is, you need to know how to program in PHP and how to access those classes). Here's an example:

```
require_once('Loader/autoloader.php');

$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('view')); 
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('edit'));
$acl->allow('guest', null, 'view');
$acl->allow('editor', array('view', 'edit'));
```

*This creates a User Role named guest and editor, and gives permissions accordingly.*

---

Wordpress is a CMS (like joomla and Drupal, for instance). You don't need any PHP knowledge to create a site with these tools and you interact with the modules in the admin level. You can actually integrate Zend Framework (or any other framework) with those CMS, but then again you need not only knowledge in PHP but also in the framework itself and in the structure of the CMS.

To summarize, PHP is powerful yet relatively easy programming language. Should you decide to learn it, you should start by doing some basic tutorials like [this one](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/php/) to familiarize yourself with the language. The learning curve might be a little steep but it pays off. Once you feel you can do most tasks, you can try to work with a framework (ZEND or SYMFONY, for instance)

If your only objective is just to build sites easily and quickly, you should use a CMS.